# Faster LIKE '%XXX'

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-like, database-optimization

In MySQL conducting a search like:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE surname LIKE '%ton';
```

Are slow, even when the column subject to the LIKE is indexed. **Are there any techniques for speeding this up?**

The best idea I can think of is:

1. Create a new column, with the column in question reversed. So Washington => notgnihsaW AND Jefferson => nosreffeJ
2. When you want to perform a LIKE '%ton' search, reverse your suffix, e.g. ton > not and then perform a LIKE 'not%' search on your new column.

This is a simple solution, but would require recompiling the reversed column whenever you add new data.

Comment: MySQL can not use an index for a condition like that. The only way to speed that up is to use the built-in full-text search

Comment: MySQL indexes use B-trees. These can only be used when the search string is a prefix of the column value. If you're looking for something in the middle of the value, it has to do sequential searching, unless you use a full-text index.

Comment: Hat's off to you, sir. Your suggestion (combined with a fulltext index) sounds excellent to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have already proposed an excellent solution for suffix matching ... store a reversed column and use it for reversed prefix matching. I've done this and it works very well indeed.

It seems like you're looking for people with surnames like Harrington, Carlton, Milton, etc.

If that's correct then FULLTEXT is not a good solution; it doesn't do partial word stemming.

Comment: I can't get FULLTEXT search to work: SELECT * FROM people WHERE MATCH( surname ) AGAINST ( '*ton' IN BOOLEAN MODE ); returns no results. 'ton*' works fine.

Comment: @KohjahBreese Did you add a fulltext index to your column?

Comment: Yes. I have put a full text index on it. There are thousands of matches for LIKE '%ton'.

Comment: "Mysql fulltext indexes support only searching for prefixes. So you can search for "foo*" but not "*foo*"". I guess it will be reverse columns then.